# Pandas Groupby AttributeError: 'StringDtype' object has no attribute 'storage'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

I have a large dataframe and I am trying to use pandas group by in combination with mean()

For example:

```
df.groupby(['id_column'])['weight'].mean()
```

If the 'id_column' is a string I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'StringDtype' object has no attribute 'storage'
```

If I convert the 'id_column' to a float I don't get the error.

If I subset the dataframe to be smaller I don't get the error e.g. only select one day of data or only select data from one id.

I am using

- Pandas Version: 1.2.5
- Version: 1.22.3

Comment: Well you have strings in the column, convert to float as you did.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I get the error even if the entire column is a string. For example, if I want to group by the column 'country'  df.groupby(['country'])['weight'].mean() where 'country' is 'Germany','France' etc

Comment: If the dataset is very very large, I wouldn’t recommend to use pandas. Pandas loads the whole dataset in memory.

Comment: Can you provide a sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I don’t understand the error, convert to float.

Comment: I think I am dealing with a package and/or version conflict. The data is a parquet file that was generated and saved to parquet using an older version of python and pandas. If run the code df=df.copy() and then run the group by code I don't get an error.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error message

```
AttributeError: 'StringDtype' object has no attribute 'storage'
```

while I was performing `set_index()`.

Since the dataframe had been loaded from a pickle,  I too thought it could be an incompatibility problem from an older pandas. So I did a `df = df.copy()` on the line just before the error, and that fixed it.